# MiNiFi gets shutdown because of bootstrap.conf file while using Command and Control (C2) Server for updating config.yml file

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

I am using Command and Control (C2) Server for automatically updating the config.yml file in minifi. C2 takes this file from templates in currently running NiFi  instance. It updates the config.yml only once at interval 1 min and after trying at second time it says:

**ERROR [pool-2-thread-2] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Failed to communicate with Bootstrap. Bootstrap may be unable to issue or receive commands from MiNiFi.**

and then it shutdown the minifi and it do not get restarted.

Note that I still haven't updated the template in NiFi so it will be asking for same config.yml file as before.

minifi-c2-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  ~ contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  ~ this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  ~ The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  ~ (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  ~ the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->
<beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="configService" class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.service.ConfigService" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.provider.cache.CacheConfigurationProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <value>text/yml</value>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.cache.filesystem.FileSystemConfigurationCache">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>./files</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>${class}/config</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.cache.s3.S3ConfigurationCache">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>bucket</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>prefix/</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                        <value>${class}</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value>access-key</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value>secret-key</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value>us-east-1</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>-->
           <bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.provider.nifi.rest.NiFiRestConfigurationProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.cache.filesystem.FileSystemConfigurationCache">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>./cache</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value>${class}/${class}</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value>http://localhost:8080/nifi-api</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value>${class}.v${version}</value>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.apache.nifi.minifi.c2.security.authorization.GrantedAuthorityAuthorizer">
            <constructor-arg value="classpath:authorizations.yaml"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

bootstrap.conf in MiNiFi

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or         implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Java command to use when running MiNiFi
java=java

# Username to use when running MiNiFi. This value will be ignored on     Windows.
run.as=

# Configure where MiNiFi's lib and conf directories live
# When running as a Windows service set full paths instead of relative paths
lib.dir=./lib
conf.dir=./conf

# How long to wait after telling MiNiFi to shutdown before explicitly     killing the Process
graceful.shutdown.seconds=20

# The location for the configuration file
# When running as a Windows service use the full path to the file
nifi.minifi.config=./conf/config.yml

# Notifiers to use for the associated agent, comma separated list of     class names
#nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors=org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.configuration.ingestors.FileChangeIngestor
#nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors=org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.configuration.ingestors.RestChangeIngestor
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors=org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.configuration.ingestors.PullHttpChangeIngestor

# File change notifier configuration

# Path of the file to monitor for changes.  When these occur, the     FileChangeNotifier, if configured, will begin the configuration reloading process
#nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.file.config.path=
# How frequently the file specified by 'nifi.minifi.notifier.file.config.path' should be evaluated for changes.
#nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.file.polling.period.seconds=5

# Rest change notifier configuration

# Port on which the Jetty server will bind to, keep commented for a random open port
#nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.receive.http.port=8338

#Pull HTTP change notifier configuration

# Hostname on which to pull configurations from
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.hostname=localhost
# Port on which to pull configurations from
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.port=10080
# Path to pull configurations from
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.path=/c2/config
# Query string to pull configurations with
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.query=class=minifidemo
# Period on which to pull configurations from, defaults to 5 minutes if     commented out
nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.period.ms=60000

# Periodic Status Reporters to use for the associated agent, comma separated list of class names
    #nifi.minifi.status.reporter.components=org.apache.nifi.minifi.bootstrap.status.reporters.StatusLogger

# Periodic Status Logger configuration

# The FlowStatus query to submit to the MiNiFi instance
#nifi.minifi.status.reporter.log.query=instance:health,bulletins
# The log level at which the status will be logged
#nifi.minifi.status.reporter.log.level=INFO
# The period (in milliseconds) at which to log the status
#nifi.minifi.status.reporter.log.period=60000

# Disable JSR 199 so that we can use JSP's without running a JDK
java.arg.1=-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true

# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms256m
java.arg.3=-Xmx256m

# Enable Remote Debugging
#java.arg.debug=-    agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

java.arg.4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

# allowRestrictedHeaders is required for Cluster/Node communications to work properly
java.arg.5=-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
java.arg.6=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol

# Sets the provider of SecureRandom to /dev/urandom to prevent blocking on VMs
java.arg.7=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom


# The G1GC is still considered experimental but has proven to be very advantageous in providing great
# performance without significant "stop-the-world" delays.
#java.arg.13=-XX:+UseG1GC

#Set headless mode by default
java.arg.14=-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

nifi.properties in minifi

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
#
#Wed Nov 20 15:01:56 IST 2019
# Core Properties #

nifi.version=1.4.0
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=false
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
nifi.variable.registry.properties=
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis

nifi.authority.provider.configuration.file=./conf/authority-providers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

##################### State Management #####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider

# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT\=25000;WRITE_DELAY\=0;AUTO_SERVER\=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.partitions=256
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=2 mins
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000
nifi.swap.in.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.in.threads=1
nifi.swap.out.period=5 sec
nifi.swap.out.threads=4

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=10 MB
nifi.content.claim.max.flow.files=100
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=false
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.MiNiFiPersistentProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=1 min

# Volatile Provenance Respository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=10000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=8081
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC

nifi.security.keystore=
nifi.security.keystoreType=
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=
nifi.security.truststoreType=
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=
nifi.security.needClientAuth=
nifi.security.user.credential.cache.duration=24 hours
nifi.security.user.authority.provider=file-provider
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
nifi.security.support.new.account.requests=
# Valid Authorities include: ROLE_MONITOR,ROLE_DFM,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_PROVENANCE,ROLE_NIFI
nifi.security.anonymous.authorities=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=


# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false

# cluster manager properties (only configure for cluster manager) #
nifi.cluster.is.manager=false
```

Comment: Could you please share your configuration of the C2 server and MiNiFi itself?  If so, feel free to upload these to a gist or similar for better readability.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the configurations as per requested.

Answer (score 0):

you can change localhost at your bootstrap.conf(raspi) to your ip address from your computer (installed c2 server)